# Remix IDE - CompilerError: Stack too deep

Tags: solidity, remix, cli

I'm learning solidity language with Remix IDE using my phone
then I encountered an error message like this:

```
CompilerError: Stack too deep. Try compiling with --via-ir (cli) or the equivalent viaIR: true (standard JSON) while enabling the optimizer. Otherwise, try removing local variables.
`principal,` code must be changed
```

[image]

**This is the code I use:**

```
    function _emit(uint256 loanId, LoanLibrary.Loan memory loan) private {
        emit LoanLibrary.LoanCreated(
            loanId,
            loan.offerId,
            loan.state,
            loan.principalToken,
            loan.collateralToken,
            loan.initialPrincipal,
            loan.currentPrincipal,
            loan.initialCollateral,
            loan.currentCollateral,
            loan.interestRate,
            loan.startDate,
            loan.maturityDate,
            loan.graceDays,
            loan.borrower,
            loan.lender
        );
```

**Or you can see the code here:**
https://wtools.io/paste-code/bOUC

Answer (score 0):

The stack-too-deep error is a commonly encountered error when writing smart contracts, especially those that deal with many different variables. See this excerpt from [this article](https://soliditydeveloper.com/stacktoodeep) that explains what it is.

> The reason is a limitation in how variables can be referenced in the
> EVM stack. While you can have more than 16 variables in it, once you
> try to reference a variable in slot 16 or higher, it will fail. It's
> therefore not always obvious why exactly some code is failing and then
> a few random changes just seem to fix it.

In your case, the error is being caused because you have too many variables inside your event's `emit`. You must either combine the variables into a `struct` and then `emit` that `struct`, or remove some of the variables.

For example this contract's function works correctly without any issue:

```
contract StackTooDeep {

event Stack(Too struc);


struct Too {
    uint num0;
    uint num1;
    uint num2;
    uint num3;
    uint num4;
    uint num5;
    uint num6;
    uint num7;
    address addr0;
    address addr1;
    address addr2;
    address addr3;
    address addr4;
    address addr5;
    address addr6;
    address addr7;
    bool bool0;
    bool bool1;
    bool bool2;
    bool bool3;
    bool bool4;
    bool bool5;
    bool bool6;
    bool bool7;
}

function deep(Too memory stu) public {
    emit Stack(stu);
}
}
```

When passed this as input to `deep()`:

```
["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7",
"0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138",
"0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138",
"0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138",
"0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138",
"0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138",
"0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138",
"0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138",
"0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138",
true,true,false,false,false,false,false,true]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a struct, are using events (indexed ones ?) and 15 variables in your function it is not surprising that you have the `stack too deep` error.

The EVM callstack can only handle properly the 16/17 elements.
For instance the `DUP` opcode can only duplicate the 16 first elements of the stack while the `SWAP` opcode can swap from the first through the 17th element.

Possible solutions would be to:

- lighten your variables in your struct.
- split your variables in several structs.
- pack your variables (learn about [variable packing here](https://fravoll.github.io/solidity-patterns/tight_variable_packing.html)).
- Use internal functions to split the input & output.

There are couples of other solutions.

Here are two useful links that will provide you explanation and possible fixes.

https://soliditydeveloper.com/stacktoodeep

https://medium.com/aventus/stack-too-deep-error-in-solidity-5b8861891bae